# Printing thread id in log file using log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I am trying to print the id of the thread for which the logging is being done in my logfile. I did it at code level by `log.info(Thread.currentThread().getId())` where "log" is Logger class object but this is not what i exactly want. Actually my application is a large distributed application and it is not possible to add `Thread.currentThread().getId()` with every `log.info("something")` in the code. Is there anyway by which i can just make any change in my log4j.xml file and print threads id for every log.info in my code. This is my log4j.xml

```
<log4j:configuration debug="true">
<!-- File Appenders -->

<appender name="EventsAndErrorsFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="EventsAndErrors.xml" />
    <param name="Datepattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000KB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="140" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%C] %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
    </filter>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="EventsAndErrorsFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ExceptionFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Now i am assuming that I can add something in my Layout in xml to print the thread.
I am also attaching the sample code in which i am trying this just for reference

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

class MyThread extends Thread implements MyInterface
  {
   public void run()
    {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"In first        thread");
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        log.error(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }   

  }
}
class MyThread1 extends Thread implements MyInterface
{

public void run()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"In secound thread");
        log.info(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        log.debug("debug");
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
}
}

public class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
    MyThread1 thread2 = new MyThread1();


    log.info("logging stareted");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
 } 
}
```

Any guidance would be aprreciated.
Thanks

Comment: %t in ConversionPattern will print Thread **name** if that is sufficient.

Comment: @Fildor. Yes , that will suffice. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 55):

In log4j 2
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

`%tid` prints the thread ID

Comment: your answer would be better added as a comment to the question.

Comment: @JavierElices Then the same could be applied to my answer. In this case there isn't really much more to say in an answer, so I think its brevity and link for reference is valid.

Comment: @Fildor, you seem to be right, but it was hard to tell at the time I wrote the comment. I was reviewing answers from novice people (1 rep). My comment has 3 upvotes and his answer another 3. It seems a draw :-). I don't mind short answers but I expect a degree of knowledge or effort in the answer. I am not an expert in the topic but your opinion and the upvotes should suffice. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 29):

`%t` in the ConversionPattern gives you the thread's name.

Not the same as Thread ID but better than nothing and works without touching the code.

**Update:** As yuugen's answer points out: **in log4j 2.x** there is `%tid` for thread id. (+1 for his answer from me, adding it here for completeness. If this helps you please upvote [*his* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702479/982149)!)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Log4j 1.x then you could create another class that implements the functions of Log4j. Modify the debug method to append the Thread Id to the message.

However, you will need to bulk replace Log4j definitions with a reference to your own log class, across your codebase. I assume you have a line at the top of your class file with something like:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class.getName());
```

And that would need to be replaced with a reference to your class instead.

As this class will be the only point that Log4j is now referenced in your Application, it makes it easy for you to replace the logging library if you ever wish to.